# How can I add the value of a variable in a loop to itself after every loop?

Tags: java

The exercise is to add the sum of all the user inputs.

I cant seem to figure out how to write sum = all the values of the "read".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter numbers:");
    while (true) {
        int read = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        if (read == 0) {
            break;
        }

        read = 

        System.out.println("Sum now: " + sum);
    }

    System.out.println("Sum in the end: " + sum);

}
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: `sum = sum + read`

Comment: Or shorter: `sum += read`

Comment: You should probably use `input.nextInt()` as well, because you immediately parse it into an `int` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = sum + read
```

or

```
sum += read
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be achieved this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter numbers:");
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (true) {
            int read = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            if (read == 0) {
                break;
            }

            sum += read;

            System.out.println("Sum now: " + sum);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sum in the end: " + sum);

}
```

Comment: Advice to close `Scanner(System.in)` is bad advice.  `System.in` should _not_ be closed, because you will be unable to ever open `System.in` again.  This might not matter when this is the entire program, but there is still no reason to close it.  It is better to suppress the warning if you do not like the warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter numbers:");
            while (sum >= 0) {
                int read = input.nextInt();
                sum +=read;
                if (read == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Sum now: " + sum);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter numbers only");
        }
        System.out.println("Sum in the end: " + sum);
    }
```